# only Response entity shown in Postman

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, postman

I have a response which produces `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` like this:

```
return Response.status(200).entity(product).entity("some message").build();
```

why postman shows me `unexpected s` in json view result and `some message` in xml view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the [Response.ResponseBuilder.entity(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html#entity-java.lang.Object-) you can see

> **public abstract Response.ResponseBuilder entity(Object entity)**
>
> Set the response entity in the builder. 
>   Any Java type instance for a response entity, that is supported by the runtime can be passed. It is the callers responsibility to wrap the actual entity with GenericEntity if preservation of its generic type is required. Note that the entity can be also set as an input stream.
>
> A specific entity media type can be set using one of the type(...) methods.

Since you call this method twice, only the last value is saved.

Since "some message" is not at all a JSON syntax, it is saying that the s (from some) is unexpected, it is expecting a {

Comment: so I can't send two entities like that?

Comment: @KhalilM You have a JSON return, so wrap those two values into a JSON.